# How to set expiration time for static files in Google flexible engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have an app.yaml file at the same level as my python application main file.
I think adding a handler in app.yaml that can config the expiration time for static folder.
How can I do the same thing in **google flexible engine**?

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/*
  expiration: "4d 5h"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the flex environment the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) file has no support for such [handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) specification.

If you're [serving the static files through your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files#serving_from_your_application) you need to check the specific intructions for the framework you're using.

If you're [serving the static files from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files#serving_from_cloud_storage) see [Setting cache parameters](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-cache):

> You can control how or if your website assets are cached by
>   configuring cache control headers. Generally, only set cache control
>   headers for objects that are accessible to all anonymous users, which
>   is a requirement for any object served from a Cloud Storage bucket as
>   part of a static website.
>
> Google Cloud Storage applies a cache control setting of 3600 seconds
>   to objects that are accessible to all anonymous users, unless you
>   specify explicit cache control settings. For examples, see the
>   [metadata page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control) of `gsutil`, the [setting object metadata page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_permissions)
>   for the Google Cloud Platform Console, or headers reference pages for
>   [XML](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#cachecontrol) and [JSON](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/parameters#cachecontrol).